# proftpd on debian - authuserfile

Tags: linux, debian, ftp

I have installed proftpd on my debian 4.0 server. I have modified the proftpd.conf file so that there is a statement for AuthUserFile, which points to a valid file. The file is configured per the proftpd specs, however the user that I have placed in this file is not able to log-in to the server. What could I be doing wrong?

AuthUserFile is of the format: username:passwd:999:1002:www:/var/www:/bin/bash

Comment: Does that user actually have permissions to access the folder /var/www?

Comment: So the user in the Auth file, even though they don't have a system profile, needs access to the directory? The group they are assigned to, which is a system group, does have access to this directory.

Comment: Does the GID you have listed in the question match the GID for the system group? If it does not match, the FTP user will be attempting to access /var/www using whatever permissions the proftpd user has.

Comment: Yes, it matches. I think this is not the problem though, because the user is not being authenticated. It's not a folder access problem.

Answer (score 1):

The entry looks okay to me.
Are there any errors in /var/log/proftpd/auth.log?

I found it easier to debug proftpd by stopping the proftpd service and running in the foreground using

```
proftpd -d 10
```

(Perhaps not 10, 5 should be ample, see `man proftpd` for options)

Then try connecting and see what errors you get.

Comment: I checked var/log/proftpd/auth.log and it has the following errors:

Aug 17 19:25:54 domain proftpd[13964] domain (IP[IP]): FTP session opened.
Aug 17 19:26:10 domain proftpd[13964] domain (IP[IP]): PAM(myuser): User not known to the underlying authentication module.
Aug 17 19:26:10 domain proftpd[13964] domain (IP[IP]):  USER myuser (Login failed): Incorrect password.

Comment: I had entered the correct password. Here is what I think is pertinent from the log...

 dispatching auth request "getpwnam" to module mod_auth_file
 mod_auth_file/0.8.3: using passwd file '/etc/proftpd/authfiles/passwd'
 stashed module 'mod_auth_file.c' for user 'myuser' in the authcache
 retrieved UID 999 for user 'myuser'
 dispatching auth request "gid2name" to module mod_radius
 dispatching auth request "gid2name" to module mod_ldap
 dispatching auth request "gid2name" to module mod_sql
 dispatching auth request "gid2name" to module mod_auth_file

Comment: dispatching auth request "gid2name" to module mod_auth_unix
 using module 'mod_auth_pam.c' to authenticate user 'myuser'
 dispatching auth request "auth" to module mod_auth_pam
 ROOT PRIVS at mod_auth_pam.c:264
 PAM(myuser): User not known to the underlying authentication module.
 RELINQUISH PRIVS at mod_auth_pam.c:423
 using module 'mod_auth_file.c' from authcache to authenticate user 'myuser'
 dispatching auth request "auth" to module mod_auth_file
 mod_auth_file/0.8.3: using passwd file '/etc/proftpd/authfiles/passwd'

Comment: using module 'mod_auth_pam.c' to authenticate user 'myuser'
 using module 'mod_auth_file.c' from authcache to authenticate user 'myuser'
 dispatching auth request "check" to module mod_auth_file
 USER myuser (Login failed): Incorrect password.

Comment: Can you post back the AuthOrder from your proftpd.conf file? 
Also do any authentication methods work? For example can you login using your normal Linux account? 
Can you rule out firewall problems (for example turn of firewall and try again)?

Comment: AuthOrder                       mod_auth_file.c

Yes, I can login with my normal Linux account. It authenticates.

Answer (score 0):

It might be helpful to turn off checking of the legacy ftpusers file using the following Directive:

```
UseFtpUsers off
```

[By default, the UseFtpUsers directive is On](http://www.proftpd.org/docs/directives/linked/config_ref_UseFtpUsers.html)

Comment: I put this in place - no go.
I noticed a line in proftpd.conf:

Include /etc/proftpd/modules.conf

It does not have mod_auth_file.c listed in the file, nor does mod_auth_file.c exist in /usr/lib/proftpd

It is supposed to be compiled by default, according to the documentation - http://www.proftpd.org/docs/modules/mod_auth_file.html

Should I be reinstalling?

Comment: Can you execute the command "proftpd -vv" and post the output here? I believe that modules listed as "compiled by default" are statically loaded in the main executable, rather than as a DSO.